# Append Selected Drop Down Value with Option in Laravel Blade with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, routes, laravel-blade

I want to show the models by changing the Drop Down value....I know how to get the value of drop down with change function but my problem is that i want to send that value in route to filter the models.....Please tell me how can i send the changed value id with route from blade..

This is my Drop Down

```
<select class="form-control" id="category" placeholder="Select category">
       <option>All</option>
       @foreach($categories as $category)
      <option value="{{route('contributors.index')}}?category={{ $category->id }}">{{$category->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

Here i my Jquery Change Function

```
  $('#category').change(function(){
            alert($(this).val());
        })
```

Explanation :

Please check the below picture....I want to show the models(in the same view)which are related to that category selected in the drop down.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain more about what you need?

Comment: check my question again...Explanation area

Comment: You wanna make an ajax call or simply refresh the page with selected id in the route?

Comment: i want a simple refresh with selected id in the route

Comment: @iCoders....can u please check this question as well and suggest me a scenerio ??

Comment: You didn't find the answer yet? what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: still looking for a solution....i dont want to filter it with ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Add this to redirect you to the specific route. For you, it refreshes the page with the selected id in URL. So, models will filter for the given category_id.

```
$('#category').change(function(){
    window.location = "domain.com/route/" + $('option:selected', this).val();
})
```

Of course, you should use your own URL instead of the URL in the example.

Comment: When user select option from drop down,the page should show the filtered models related to that option..

Comment: And you filter those models through and Id in the route. right?

Comment: So, the above code should work with little changes in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax call to append and send category value to your route

```
$( "#category" ).change(function() {
  var id=$(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: your url goes here,
        success: function (data) {
           //here yuo can append to model div
        },
        error: function (data) {

            console.log(data);

        }
    });

});
```

the above code is sample for ajax request